# What is the difference between laravel Form::open and Form::model

Tags: php, laravel

```
1. {{Form::model($message,['route' => ['message.update',$message->id]])}}  
2. {{Form::open(['route' => ['message.update',$message->id]])}}
```

What is the difference between these above two lines?

I return `$message` from controller. And the input I rendered in view is

`{!!Form::text("text",isset($message) ? $message->title : NULL,["class" => "form-control"])!!}`

It works for above two statements.

1. So what is the aim of laravel form binding?
2. How should I use it effectively?

Answer (score 5):

`Form::open()` is Opening A Form.

`Form::model()` is Form Model Binding and used in update delete operation.when you generate a form element, like a text input, the model's value matching the field's name will automatically be set as the field value. So, for example, for a text input named email, the user model's email attribute would be set as the value.
[source](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#form-model-binding)

example when you `Form::open()`

```
{!!Form::text("text",isset($message) ? $message->title : NULL,["class" => "form-control"])!!}
```

if you bind form `Form::model()`

```
{!!Form::text("text",null,["class" => "form-control"])!!}
```

no need of conditions or define any variable like `$message->title`  it automatically set.

Answer (score 0):

Form::model binding allows you to associate a form with one of your application’s models, and automatically:

a) matches inputs named after model fields

b) populates the form’s fields with an existing model object’s data if you’re editing and existing object

c) repopulates the form with session data (say, if you’ve redirected to show validation errors after a failed object creation

Syntax : `{{ Form::model($modelInstance, ['route'=>'your route','method'=>'']) }}`

The Form::Open i.e `{{ Form::open(['route'=>'your-route']) }}` allows you to open new form with hidden csrf token field attach automatically and repopulates the form with session data (say, if you’ve redirected to show validation errors after a failed object creation